# AWS EC2 Task/Service container with java command in the container definitions

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

We need to deploy a docker container on AWS EC2, Hawkbit and RabbitMQ will be running on the container. We tried to put the java command in the command section of the container definitions, when setting up our task placement.

Alas when we launch the service, the container stops, because AWS apparently does not execute the java command.

is there a way to give the container the java command without SSH'ing into the container?

Answer (score 0):

(AWS employee here)

For the first step can you launch the docker container and get it to stay up locally? If the container does not stay up locally it will not stay up on ECS either.

If your container stays up locally but not on ECS then there is probably a difference in the docker run command. Are you passing in an environment variable or defining a custom volume or something else that is required for the container to run? ECS will generate a docker run command using the parameters that you define in your task definition, and if your task definition is missing something required for your docker run statement that may explain the issue.

You should also hook your container up to a cloudwatch log group and check that log group for log statements that may help you diagnose why your java process is not starting. If possible can you copy and paste the log output here?

Comment: thank you for your answer, we solved the problem by using the run command, so the hawkbit java service started. I've followed the quickstart Install and Configure the CloudWatch Logs Agent on a Running EC2 Instance, but i'l not getting any logs, so there's some work for me there ;).